# Vertica - is there a way of retrieving the rejected records by code?

Tags: vertica

The "REJECTMAX" parameter is a technique of executing copy command even though there are invalid records in the csv

(so if i have 100 records, 9 of them are invalid & max rejected is 10 the file will upload)

I wonder if there is a way that i can get as a text the rejected records that prints into the rejected file so i can log it into application error log.

Comment: To ask the obvious, does your source data records have any sort of primary key which could be used to discriminate which records were inserted/rejected?

Comment: no.............

Comment: Are you already seeing the rejected-data file but it doesn't contain what you expect, or have you not seen that file yet?

Comment: Why don`t you store the rejects as Table and then work on top of that table.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example on how to use REJECTED DATA. Suppose you have a table like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE public.mydata ( id INTEGER ) ;
CREATE TABLE
```

and an input file containing:

```
$ cat /tmp/mydata
1
2
3
ABC 
4
5
```

Clearly `ABC` won't fit into an integer...

So we run:

```
SQL> COPY public.mydata FROM '/tmp/mydata' REJECTMAX 2 REJECTED DATA '/tmp/mydata.rejected' ;
NOTICE 7850:  In a multi-threaded load, rejected record data may be written to additional files
HINT:  Rejected data may be written to files [/tmp/mydata.rejected],    [/tmp/mydata.rejected.1], etc
 Rows Loaded 
-------------
       5
```

And now...

```
$ cat /tmp/mydata.rejected 
ABC
```

Is this what you were looking for?